# Get XML child node from parent node using XPATH java

Tags: java, xml, xpath, rss, javax.xml

I'm trying to get specific child node from list of nodes using xpath.

Here is my xml input

```
<root>
    <Transaction>
        <code> 123 </code>
        <Reason> test1 </Reason>
    </Transaction>
    <Transaction>
        <code> 456 </code>
    </Transaction>
    <Transaction>
        <code> 789 </code>
        <Reason> test2 </Reason>
    </Transaction>
</root>
```

I'm trying to get all the transactions as node list and then check one by one inside each trancation either it has reason or not all using Xpath. Here is my sample code.

```
    Document document = builder.parse(new FileInputStream(file));

    XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

    //Get all the transactions
    NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate("//Transaction", document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    
    
    for (int temp = 0; temp < nodeList.getLength(); temp++) {

        Node node = nodeList.item(temp);
        Element element = (Element) node;
        
        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            XPath xPath2 = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            
            //This one always return first value
            Node child = (Node) xPath2.evaluate("//Reason", node, XPathConstants.NODE);
            
            if(child != null) {
                System.out.println(child.getTextContent());
            }
            
            //This is working as expected
            if(element.getElementsByTagName("Reason").getLength() > 0) {
                System.out.println(element.getElementsByTagName("Reason").item(0).getTextContent());
            }

        }
    }
```

If I cast the node to element and try to get child element by tag name it's working fine. But when I try to do it using X-PAth it returns all the values from other nodes as well.

Comment: Change `//Reason` to `.//Reason`.  Starting the expression with a slash searches from the root of the document, not relative to the node.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm just confused when I'm passing a specific node to evaluate why it's considering complete document.

Comment: Because that’s what starting an expression with a slash means.  File names work the same way:  `data.txt` is a file relative to the current directory, but `/data.txt` is always located in the root of the file system.  In general, starting a path with a slash is an absolute path, and any other path string is a relative path.

Comment: "why it's considering complete document.": you might only want to look at the subtree for your use case but XPath is more powerful and let's you navigator to sibling, ancestors, preceding or following elements, the root, as that is useful for other cases.

Comment: Thanks @MartinHonnen, that's the thing cnfusing me. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to execute the loop in Java; you can do it in the XPath expression itself:

```xml
//Transaction[Reason]
```

That XPath will return you all the `Transaction` elements which have a child `Reason` element.

If you want to get the `Reason` elements which are children of a `Transaction` element, then use this XPath:

```xml
//Transaction/Reason
```

If you want to get all the text nodes which are children of `Reason` elements which are children of a `Transaction` element, then use this XPath:

```xml
//Transaction/Reason/text()
```